# IIf and OR in Access query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am analyzing an old access query where I have got an expression in `Having` clause as

```
(((IIf([Student_id] Like 'I*','IA',IIf([Student_id] Like 'D*','IA',[Student_id]))) Like 'R*'
Or (IIf([Student_id] Like 'I*','IA',IIf([Student_id] Like 'D*','IA',[Student_id]))) Like 'N*'
Or (IIf([Student_id] Like 'I*','IA',IIf([Student_id] Like 'D*','IA',[Student_id])))=" "))
```

In the above query, I am wondering what does `IIf([Student_id] Like 'I*','IA'` means and what these three `(IIf([Student_id] Like 'I*','IA',IIf([Student_id] Like 'D*','IA',[Student_id]))) Like 'R*'` doing with `Like 'R*`. Finally the `OR` condition.

Answer (score 2):

The IIf function is an if / else where:

- the first parameter is the expression to evaluate
- the second parameter is the value to return if the result of the expression is true
- the third parameter is the value to return is the result of the expression is false

`IIf ( expr , truepart , falsepart )`

Since the truepart or the falsepart can also be an expression you can nest calls to IIf which is potentially powerful but can be a pain to read.

So if we start with the first bit and indent to show the structure:

`(((
IIf([Student_id] Like 'I*',
  'IA',
   IIf([Student_id] Like 'D*',
       'IA',
       [Student_id]))) 
Like 'R*'`

So its staying if the Student_ids start with I then the result is IA else the result is evaluation of if student ids start with D then the result is IA else the result is the student id.

Having evaluated the expression, does the result start with R

Same but comparing to see if the resulting ID starts with N

Same but comparing to see if the resulting ID is " "

So the nasty nested IIf calls are a filter to exclude student Ids that start with I or D.

Fundamentally that's just a mess.

Comment: `So the nasty nested IIf calls are a filter to exclude student Ids that start with I or D` . I understood this line, but still confused with `if the Student_ids start with I then IA `.Could you please explain this.